# amplifier circuit

Tags: amplifier, audio

[image: circuit diagram]

i am working on a circuit in which it has taken a telephone buzzer signal and connected it to 340 ohm resistance then 100nf capacitor and then to the transformer with input coil impedence 45ohm and output coil impedence 55 ohm and then connected it to 4.7nf and then given this signal to 15watt amplifier, circuit is working. can you explain the circuit and how to choose capacitor value, what is the role of capacitor , transformer working and what happen if we don't use transformer and vice versa.

i have taken from telephone, telephone buzzer signal and the amplifier that is used is tda2030a

Comment: You would have to tell from where some "telephone buzzer" signal comes from and what the "amplifier" looks like? This circuit just sits between two unknown systems and without knowig how exactly those systems work, we can't say why all these components are necessary and how their values are calculated.

Comment: i have taken from telephone, telephone buzzer signal and the amplifier that is used is tda2030a

Comment: But what do you mean with a telephone buzzer signal? Does it connect to land line wires directly? What kind of buzzer there is, is that a bell ringer, mechanical buzzer, piezo element or just a speaker? We cannot know what is it that you are doing unless you give all the details.

Comment: Please correct the text according to basic spelling rules.